# Unable to edit data in cakephp

Tags: mysql, cakephp-2.0

i am developing a mobile app using cakephp2.4.0. i am having issue while updating users information.means user is unable to save data the function for editing is as

```
public function edit_profile() {
   // $this->layout='';
    $getId=$this->request->data['Id'];
        $this->User->id=1;
    if($this->request->is('post')){
        $getId=$this->request->data['Id'];
       // $this->User->id=$getId;
            if(!$this->User->exists($getId)){
                echo json_encode("Invalid User");
                return;
            }
            else{
                if($this->User->save($this->request->data)){
                    echo json_encode("User has been saved");
                    return;
                }
                else{
                    echo json_encode($this->request->data);
                    echo json_encode($this->User->save($this->request->data));
                    return;
                }
            }
    }

}
```

it is sending json response with request data not sending User has been saved string. 
I am not getting any error of mysql in return response.i am unable to know what is the issue at backend why is it not editing data?

Comment: Actually i was sending all of the fields from android app as a string. Here on edit_profile function i was not casting them back to int some while validation it did not save the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually i was sending all of the fields from android app as a string. Here on edit_profile function i was not casting them back to int some while validation it did not save the data